# Printing a word of a sentence in C?

Tags: c

I try to understand something about char.

I wrote this code but it gives error.Why is it not possible if I scan "Hello world", and get only "Hello" with this code? (I thought st1[0]=Hello st1[1]=world)

How can I do it?

```
char st1[100];
gets(st1);
printf("%s",st1[0]);
```

Comment: `st1[0]` is a `char`, not a string.

Comment: Also, it's not advised to use `gets`. I would suggest you look up `fgets` instead.

Comment: The function has been depricated, for reasons relating to buffer overflow.

Comment: `I wrote this code but it gives error`, yes, it _should_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have posted is most probably not quite the code you use (see my item 2 below).

1. Note the compiler is probably giving you a hint for the line which contains the printf() call. The issue is you store a string of characters in st1[]. In C, strings of characters (a.k.a. C-strings) are stored in null-terminated char arrays (=char arrays terminated with the ASCII code 0, a.k.a. '\0', character). When you write st1[0] - this means just a single (the first one) character from the array, not the whole, null-terminated C-string.
2. Your code consists of two parts: scanning the data in, and outputting it. For your current question you only need to correct outputting (but also see my following point on gets()): 

   `char st1[100];
   gets(st1);
   printf("%s",st1); //this is where you need a correction`

   ...as the "%s" sequence in formatting string makes printf() expect an address, and the name of array (st1) decays to a pointer (address) in C. Your error is in using indexing (st1[]), which does not mean 'address', but which means 'take just one character from the table'. Obviously this first character ('H' in case you have typed 'Hello') is totally unrelated with the memory address the whole array is at. It is also very unlikely that by accident it points to some 'Hello' string that your report (therefore I suppose the code is not exactly what you have run).
3. As for now, I am leaving aside the question of your use of get(), which should be considered insecure. Consider using fgets() instead. Or you will note strange behavior when a user tries to enter more characters than you have room for in your st1[], and the computer starts to overwrite other parts of program stack, destroying your other, innocent variables.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways... The most simple one would be to do the following:

```
char *str1[] = {"Hello", "World"};
```

And now the words are stored in splited arrays. To access 'Hello' use `str1[0]`.

Another way would be to print char by char until you have printed 'Hello'.

Example (Where str1 is the one in your code):

```
for(int x = 0; x < strlen("Hello") && x < strlen(str1); x++)
    printf("%c", str1[x]);
```

To your mistake:

A string in C is just an array of chars, so the first element of the String 'Hello World' would be 'H', the second would be 'e' and so on..

Answer (score 0):

`st1[0]` is only the first character in the phrase. You can iterate until you match a `' '` (space) or reach the end of the string:

```
char st1[100];
gets(st1);
for (int i=0; i<100 && st1[i]!=' '; ++i) {
    printf("%c",st1[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `puts(st1)` for printing strings.
by putting `st1[0]` in the printf you told the program to print only the first element of the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char x[100];
    gets(x);
    puts(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`st1[0]` is a char, not a C-string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char st1[100];

    if(fgets(st1, sizeof st1, stdin)){
        char *p = strchr(st1, ' ');
        if(p != NULL)
            *p = 0;
        printf("%s\n", &st1[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```